# volleyのpost送信で「BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 412 volley」エラー

Tags: android, android-volley

volleyでpost送信を行った場合に以下のエラーがでており、volleyのソースを追っていますが、改善に至りませんので、こちら質問させていただきました

エラー内容
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 412 volley

コード：

```
RequestQueue mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/volley/person_object.json";
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,url, null,
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
            return params;
        }

    };

mQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
```

事象切り分け：
Method.POSTをMethod.GETとした場合はonResponseとなり正常にデータを取得できています。

POSTにした場合に動作していません。

よろしくお願いいたします。